# Amazon MWS API PHP Samples return internal server error 500

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I have been trying to use a sample from Amazon MWS API but whatever I do I always get blank page with error 500.

I have setup the IDs correctly. 
cURL is up and running
The server has correct SSL certificates (I tried the samples on two different servers I have)
I have tried a sample on the scratchpad and it works

Does anyone have an idea about this problem?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What's in the server error log?

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Client' not found in /var/www/vhosts/domainname/httpdocs/amazonmws/Samples/ListOrdersSample.php on line 53

Comment: It seems your sample code is missing one or more files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the MWS SDK `__autoload` function is having trouble finding the MWS Class files. Take a look in the .config.inc.php file for that function definition. I think you'll find it in the 'Samples' directory.

Make sure that .config.inc.php is getting included in the sample script you're trying to run. It might help to print out the include path the script is using by adding `echo get_include_path();` in the sample script and temporarily commenting out the line that is throwing fatal errors. If the correct path to your MWS class files is not printed out with `get_include_path()` you'll need to add in a `set_include_path()` call in .config.inc.php to get the `__autoload` function to work correctly.

For example:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'my/MWS_SDK/path/');
```